# Using two ArangoSearch Views in a traversal

Tags: arangodb

Consider the following dataset:

```
arangosh> db.createDocumentCollection('city')
arangosh> db.createDocumentCollection('colour')
arangosh> db._createEdgeCollection('likes')

LET cities = 
[
  {
    "key": "1",
    "cities": ["toronto", "kingston"]
  },
  {
    "key": "2",
    "cities": ["seattle", "kingston"]
  },
  {
    "key": "3",
    "cities": ["seat", "kingston"]
  },
  {
    "key": "4",
    "cities": ["toronto", "seattle"]
  }
]

FOR c IN cities
    INSERT c INTO city
    RETURN NEW

LET colours = [
  {
    "key": "1",
    "colors": ["red", "love green"]
  },
  {
    "key": "2",
    "colors": ["we like red", "blue and purple"]
  },
  {
    "key": "3",
    "colors": ["grassy green"]
  },
  {
    "key": "4",
    "colors": ["red"]
  },
  {
    "key": "5",
    "colors": ["red"]
  },
  {
    "key": "6",
    "colors": ["red", "green"]
  }
]

FOR c IN colours
    INSERT c INTO colour
    RETURN NEW

LET likes = [
  {
    "from": "city/1", "to": "colour/3"
  },
  {
    "from": "city/1", "to": "colour/1"
  },
  {
    "from": "city/2", "to": "colour/3"
  },
  {
    "from": "city/3", "to": "colour/2"
  },
  {
    "from": "city/3", "to": "colour/3"
  },
  {
    "from": "city/3", "to": "colour/5"
  },
  {
    "from": "city/4", "to": "colour/5"
  },
  {
    "from": "city/4", "to": "colour/6"
  }
]

FOR l IN likes
    INSERT l INTO likes
    RETURN NEW


arangosh> db._createView("city_v", "arangosearch");
arangosh> var link = { 
  includeAllFields: false,
  fields : { cities : { analyzers : [ "text_en" ] } }
};
arangosh> db._view("city_v").properties({ links: { city: link }});


arangosh> db._createView("colour_v", "arangosearch");
arangosh> var link = { 
  includeAllFields: false,
  fields : { colors : { analyzers : [ "text_en" ] } }
};
arangosh> db._view("colour_v").properties({ links: { colour: link }});
```

`FOR p IN city_v SEARCH ANALYZER (p.cities == 'toronto', 'text_en') RETURn p._id` returns

```
[
  "city/1",
  "city/4"
]
```

`FOR p IN colour_v SEARCH ANALYZER (p.colors == 'green', 'text_en') RETURn p._id` returns

```
[
  "colour/1",
  "colour/3",
  "colour/6"
]
```

I need help with writing a query that would return the `city and colour` combinations where `city`  satisfies the ArangoSearchView of `toronto` that like `colours` that satisfy the ArangoSearchView of `green`.

The result sould be:  `city/1 —> colour/3` and `city/1 —> city/1` and `city/4 —> city/6`

While I  understand that this example could use a FULLTEXT  index or some other `FILTER` mechanism, the goal is to use the search features of ArangoSearch Views to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you slightly change your model like this:

```
LET cities = 
[
  {
    "_key": "1",
    "cities": ["toronto", "kingston"]
  },
  {
    "_key": "2",
    "cities": ["seattle", "kingston"]
  },
  {
    "_key": "3",
    "cities": ["seat", "kingston"]
  },
  {
    "_key": "4",
    "cities": ["toronto", "seattle"]
  }
]

FOR c IN cities
    INSERT c INTO city
    RETURN NEW

LET colours = [
  {
    "_key": "1",
    "colors": ["red", "love green"]
  },
  {
    "_key": "2",
    "colors": ["we like red", "blue and purple"]
  },
  {
    "_key": "3",
    "colors": ["grassy green"]
  },
  {
    "_key": "4",
    "colors": ["red"]
  },
  {
    "_key": "5",
    "colors": ["red"]
  },
  {
    "_key": "6",
    "colors": ["red", "green"]
  }
]

FOR c IN colours
    INSERT c INTO colour
    RETURN NEW

LET likes = [
  {
    "_from": "city/1", "_to": "colour/3"
  },
  {
    "_from": "city/1", "_to": "colour/1"
  },
  {
    "_from": "city/2", "_to": "colour/3"
  },
  {
    "_from": "city/3", "_to": "colour/2"
  },
  {
    "_from": "city/3", "_to": "colour/3"
  },
  {
    "_from": "city/3", "_to": "colour/5"
  },
  {
    "_from": "city/4", "_to": "colour/5"
  },
  {
    "_from": "city/4", "_to": "colour/6"
  }
]

FOR l IN likes
    INSERT l INTO likes
    RETURN NEW
```

And run the query below:

```
LET clr = (FOR p IN colour_v SEARCH ANALYZER (p.colors == 'green', 'text_en') RETURN p)
FOR doc IN city_v SEARCH ANALYZER (doc.cities == 'toronto', 'text_en')
FOR v,e,p in 1..1 OUTBOUND doc likes
  filter p.vertices[1] in clr
  RETURN {"v":v,"e":e,"p":p}
```